# How can I link some device (given by its device ID) with an specific firmware?

Tags: usb, udev, firmware, dvb

Imagine I have a new device which it's not working on Linux. I get its device ID with `lsusb`:

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID`**`1164:7efd`**`YUAN High-Tech Development Co., Ltd`

Imagine I know that this device will work with this firmware `/lib/firmware/dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw`

Then I would like to create a rule or something that could tell the operating system that the device `1164:7efd` must be loaded with the firmware `dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw`

I just want to link the device ID with the firmware, so my device will work. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: never done this myself ... maybe this link will give you some hint?  http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/loading-firmware-on-usb-device-with-udev-679598/

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!